# How to close activity without destroying it?

Tags: android, android-activity, ads, interstitial

Ok so first, I have menu with 3 buttons leading to 3 different layouts.
What I want, I want to show interstitial ad when I close my application.
What happens, In order to save memory I had to add finish() on every button so it doesn't take all memory. And when I click on any button interstitial ad shows.

Whats the problem,  I can't set my code to show interstitial only when I completely close app not when I switch activities 
My code:

```
package puske.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.ads.*;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;

public class Menu extends Activity implements AdListener {
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "ID");

    // Create ad request
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

    // Begin loading your interstitial
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
    interstitial.setAdListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
{



Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.menu1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, Rifles.class));
        finish();

    }
});
Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.menu2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, Pistols.class));
        finish();
    }

});



Button button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.menu3);
button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, Snipers.class));
        finish();
        }
});
}
  }


  @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            interstitial.show();
            super.onDestroy();
             // explicitly release media player
            unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.menuzor));
            System.gc();
  }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            try
            {
                ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            }
            catch(UnsupportedOperationException ignore)
            {
            }
}
}



    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Please dont show an interstitial ad when users leave your app

Comment: Why? Then what do you suggest, where should I put one? I don't want my users to be annoyed by too many adds. And only banner ads in my opinion is not enough.

Comment: It's like showing a popup window in the browser when I'm trying to close the page.

Comment: Good point and indeed that is annoying.

Comment: Don't call finish(). That will definitely destroy your activity.

Comment: When launching activities use Intents and don't call finish() on the calling activity. The OS will take care of memory management.

Comment: What should I put instead of finish?
on pause and in other activities onResume?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this picture
[image]

onPause or onStop();
Just try

Comment: Thanks but I found answer by : Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, MenuActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);  // set the flag
startActivity(i);

Comment: @Sabroan okay great :)